# Python regex: findall with parentheses inside

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```
x="From Daniel: dani78.72.dom@gmail.com UTC-8"
y=re.findall("^From (\S+@\S+)",x)
```

I want the output to be:

```
[dani78.72.dom@gmail.com]
```

but it gives me an empty list, I really need the line to start with "From".

[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following python3 code. Using Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module here and its [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall) function.

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vHHOFb/1) for used regex.

```py
import re
x="From Daniel: dani78.72.dom@gmail.com UTC-8"
re.findall(r'^From\s+.*?:\s(\S+@\S+)\s+UTC-\d+$',x)

['dani78.72.dom@gmail.com']
```

Comment: ...but would this find _other_ email addresses in the input?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, that's why I always write, codes are written and tested with shown samples. If OP comes back with anything will be happy to edit solution, cheers.